# How to setup a pre-emptive real time kernel in Yocto for a evalboard(which has a preset kernel from the manufacturer)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time, embedded-linux, yocto

I like to play around with a pre-emptive linux kernel and Yocto.
As hardware the SAMA5D3x Evalboard + SAMA5D35-CM module is used.

Atmel is providing a meta-atmel layer, which includes the "at91-linux_*.bb" recipe. This recipe builds the kernel for the SAMA5D3x machines.

For using the realtime kernel I should insert the realtime patches and activate them at the [kernel config](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#kernel-types).

I did not found a tutorial how to do this with an existing kernel. My question is:

**How/where to modify a given kernel recipe to make it a realtime kernel(preempt-rt)?**

My test project is located at the
project dir "/home/user/yocto". It has following content:

- "/[yocto git clone](https://www.yoctoproject.org/downloads)"  ==> Yocto system
- "/[meta-openembedded](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/)" ==> meta embedded recipes
- "/[meta-atmel](https://github.com/linux4sam/meta-atmel)" ==> atmels yocto layer
- "/meta-atmel/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-at91_4.4.bb" ==> the kernel recipe
- "/meta-atmel/conf/machine/sama5d3xek.conf" ==> the machine that run the kernel
- "/myTest" ==> my test project
- "/myTest/recipes-kernel/linux-at91_%.bbappend" ==> replace the kernel config  + add own device tree
- "/myTest/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-at91/sama5d3xek/defconfig" ==> my own kernel config
- /myTest/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-at91/sama5d3xek/myDev.dts ==> my own device tree

Any ideas/tutorials how to manage to activate the RT-Kernel in Yocto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general:

in `.../source/poky/recipes-kernel/linux` you should find a `linux-yocto-rt_X.XX.bb` recipe to compile a full preemptive RT kernel.

For meta-atmel you should do:

1. Download the correct RT patch for your kernel version and apply it using a .bbappend file to your current linux kernel recipe. You could find the patch [HERE](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/)
2. Add the patch to your `bbappend` file (stored in your own layer in the one of accepted direcotries). p.e.: `SRC_URI += "file://0001-linux-rt.patch"`
3. Activate preemptive kernel. Manually set `CONFIG_PREEMPT=y` at defconfig at your layer. Alternativly you can use `bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig`

Pitfalls at meta-atmel:

1. the linux-at91_4.4.bb recipe does not care about patch and sublevel of the kernel (p.e. 4.4.66 -> ..). if there is a new version at [at91-linux](https://github.com/linux4sam/linux-at91) it will go after some time to the meta-atmel layer.
2. the RT branch of the linux kernel is not provided for every new sublevel
3. this means constant breaks of your own meta-layer

Comment: Downloading the patch and applying seems to be the best for me.

The meta-atmel at91-linux is following the 4.4.x kernel. Is there a automatic way how to select the rt-patch automaticly, download, extract and deploy it? Maybe add some code at "linux-at91_%.bbappend"? Like "do_installl_append"

Comment: You can use `SRC_URI` in your recipe to retrieve the file on the web. But I suggest you to move the kernel sources (tar.gz) into your own layer and manually download the patch for it. In this way you are sure, in future, to have the correct sources and the correct patch. Many times repos are moved or became unreachable and you'll struggle a lot to correctly redirect your recipes.

Comment: so true. I contacted Nicolas who is maintaining the meta-atmel. Lets wait for his opinion about the "yocto way" to do this task. I am tending to download and store the patches different for the different kernel versions at my meta layer - like you suggest.

Comment: Is it sufficient to only set *CONFIG_PREEMPT=y* and not additionally  *CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT=y* and/or *CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y* ?  And do these patches https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt contain all the patches needed for *CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT=y* and *CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y* or just the ones needed for *CONFIG_PREEMPT=y* ?